# How to differentiate between a local user and domain user that are cached tiles on login screen from my credential provider

Tags: windows, visual-c++, registry, credential-providers

I am developing a credential provider in windows and in the credential provider I am invoking another .exe and I need to pass username as argument in `UPN` format i.e for `local user: user@machineName` and for `domain user: user@domainName`. Here the problem is for cached tiles on login screen in windows, how can I know if the cached user trying to login from my credential provider is domain user or local user?

Comment: In which function do you have to check this? Inside `GetSerialization`?

Comment: Yes, I figured out that I am getting the domain name along with user name in `_pszQualifiedUserName` which should help me to differentiate, but thanks for taking time to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I am getting the domain name along with user name in `_pszQualifiedUserName` in the flat name format i.e `Domain\username` in `GetSerialization()` which should help me to differentiate between domain and local user.